# How can i fix my code to loop right my Hangman Game?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

My code seems to be good but loop doesn't continue

```
def play(word, lives):

    print(f"You have {lives} lives! Goodluck!")
    print("_ " * len(word))
    letter = input("Provide your letter please! ")
    word_split = list(word)

    for i in range(len(word_split)):
        if word_split[i] != letter:
            word_split[i] = "_"
            continue

    print(" ".join(word_split))

play('Codecool', 6)
```

Without it i wont invent any "lives -= 1" or another letters in my code.

Comment: What loop?.....

Comment: I'm sorry if i post something wrong - I'm a new. Well i though that "for i in range..... " is a loop that iterates through letters in my word - and if my input is "o" it shows it  - and that works. Thank you for your answer

Comment: `continue` means: go back to the `for` statement and process the next item of the loop. `continue` at that point is useless, because it's the last statement of the `for` loop. At that point, the loop will go to the next item automatically. `continue` only makes sense if you have statements after `continue`.

Comment: Thats correct but as you said, that works, its unclear what you're asking about

Comment: What you really need is another loop which lets the player enter another letter

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my question - i'll try to make my posts more understable for everyone next time. i didn't understand why my code stops running after my loop - wanted to work it after to find another letters in the word.

Comment: Thomas - that's interesting i will consider that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def play(word, lives):

    print(f"You have {lives} lives! Goodluck!")
    
    word_split = list(word)
    secret_word=['_' for i in range(len(word))]
    while lives!=0:
        print(*secret_word)
        letter = input("Provide your letter please! ")
        for i in range(len(word_split)):
            if word_split[i]==letter:
                secret_word[i]=letter


        lives-=1


play('Codecool', 6)
```

Try this one , I think it might solve your problem and with this approach you can improve your game as well . I tried to keep it basic.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried this code - and now gonna analyse it :) Cheers for You! Loop in loop was the answer